# Comparing two arrays with each other

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve some problems in ruby get a hold. 
I am trying compare two arrays with each other.

```
Array1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1]
Array2=  [0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I am getting this input from the user. Then I am comparing the votes. If both persons have upvoted `1` at same index, I am trying increment an empty array by 1.

```
def count_votes
  bob_votes = gets.chomp
  alice_votes = gets.chomp
  bvotes = bob_votes.split('')
  avotes = alice_votes.split('')
  common_upvotes = []
  bvotes.each.with_index(0) do |el, i|
    if bvotes[i] == 1
    common_upvotes << 1
  end
end
```

I actually want to compare `avotes` with `bvotes` and then increment empty array by 1. I need a little help

Comment: You aren't "comparing two for loops with each other".... sounds like you want to compare two arrays to each other? And it's a little unclear what you want. Sounds like you have a 3rd array `common_upvotes`... do you want it to have the same number of elements and have a 0 where `bvotes` and `avotes` aren't both 1? Or what?

Comment: You are right. That should have been the right title. All I was thinking about was loops so I posted like that.

Comment: can you show us what you expect the result to be?

Comment: Array1 = [0,1,0,1,0,1] , Array2 = [1,0,1,1,0,1], After comparing it should be 3. Coz both have liked 4th and 6th index and disliked 5th.

Comment: @user3576036 why should this be 3?

Comment: user3576036, when clarifying a question please edit the question rather than elaborating in comments, as not all readers read all comments.  Your question could be interpreted in three ways: 1) you want to know the number of times both users upvoted (what you said in the question); 2) you wish to construct an array that contains indices `i` for which `Array1[i] == Array2[i]` (from your code) and 3) the number of times both users voted the same (from your last comment above). Please correct the question by editing. (cont.)

Comment: ... I sugggest you forget about "users" and "upvotes", as that is unnecessary and complicating. Just say, "I wish to construct an array that contains indices `i` for which `Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i]`" or I wish to return a count of the number of indices `i` for which  `Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i]`" (or  `Array1[i] == Array2[i]`, depending on what you want).

Comment: In my first comment above, by "what you said in the question", I was thinking of the term "incrementing". You applied that to an array, which makes no sense, so I viewed that as incrementing a count.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am abstracting out the original question as much as possible. Point taken. I'll make it as precise as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
array1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1]
array2=  [0,0,1,0,1,0]
array1.zip(array2)
#⇒ [[1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
array1.zip(array2).count { |v1, v2| v1 == v2 && v1 == 1 }
#⇒ 2
```

or (credits to @engineersmnky):

```
array1.zip(array2).count { |v1, v2| v1 & v2 == 1 }
```

or even better (credits to @Stefan):

```
array1.zip(array2).count { |values| values.all?(1) }
```

or

```
array1.
  zip(array2).
  reject { |v1, v2| v1 == 0 || v2 == 0 }.
  count
#⇒ 2
```

*Sidenote:* capitalized `Array1` declares *a constant*. To declare a variable, use `array1` instead.

Comment: Bitwise And? `array1.zip(array2).count { |v1, v2| v1 & v2 == 1 }` or `array1.each_with_index.count { |n,i| array2[i] & n  == 1}`

Comment: IMO, `v1 & v2 == 1` is confusing. It looks like _"both, v1 and v2 are equal to 1"_ but that is not how it's working. Maybe `count { |vs| vs.all?(1) }` would be a better choice.

Comment: @Stefan well technically speaking that is the only way it works for the data set given. Both `v1` and `v2` would have to be equal to `1` for bitwise AND to return 1 (assuming all values are 0 and 1)

Comment: @engineersmnky I understand how it works, I just say that it _appears_ to work differently at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

The number of indices `i` for which `Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i] == 1` is

```
Array1.each_index.count { |i| Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i] == 1  }
  #=> 2
```

The array of indices `i` for which `Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i] == 1` is

```
Array1.each_index.select { |i| Array1[i] == 1 && Array2[i] == 1  }
  #=> [2, 4]
```

The number of indices `i` for which `Array1[i] == Array2[i]` is

```
Array1.each_index.count { |i| Array1[i] == Array2[i] }
  #=> 4
```

Comment: `size.times` → `each_index`

Comment: Thank you, @Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a new array tracking the index where there is a match of upvotes:

```
a1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1]
a2=  [0,0,1,0,1,0]
p [a1, a2].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:&)}

#=> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

For just counting, this is another way:

```
a1 = [1,0,1,0,1,1]
a2=  [0,0,1,0,1,0]

votes = 0
a1.each_with_index do |a1, idx|
  votes +=1 if (a1 + a2[idx]) == 2
end

p votes #=> 2
```

In one line:

```
a1.each_with_index { |a1, idx| votes += 1 if (a1 + a2[idx]) == 2 }
```

Comment: The first part should probably read *"build an `Array` with [matching 1s]"* because I would consider `0` and `0` a "match" but I would not consider `1` and `0` a "match"